# HABTM.empty? not working in where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, where-clause, has-and-belongs-to-many

My Person model has and belongs to many Accounts.

I'm trying to get a list of all "orphaned" people, those not tied to any accounts yet.

`Person.where( :accounts.empty? )` throws an error because the symbol :accounts has no empty? method.

`Person.all.collect {|per| per unless per.accounts.empty?}` returns every person.

```
Person.all.each |per|
   if per.accounts.empty?
      puts per.id
   end
end
```

That one properly prints out the ids of every orphaned person.  What's the syntax I'm struggling to achieve? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Person.includes(:accounts).where( :accounts => { :id => nil } )
```